# Using drop-down list to change multiple values in separate table cells

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with 3 "main" cells (2 more tables nested inside 2 of these cells; I enabled a blue border around the cells in case it helps visually): Category (top, spanning across 2 columns), Title/Subtitle (left column), and Result (right column).

The left column does not (and should not) change at all. In the Category cell at top, there is a drop-down list and my goal is for when a category is selected, it should update all cells down the right column.

code:

```css
#tablemobile {
  /*width: 100%;*/
}
#tmcategory {
  text-align: center;
}
.tmsubtitle {
  color: blue;
  font-style: italic;
    }
.tmtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  display: inline-block;
}
#tablemobile td {
  height: 80px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<form id="tablemobile" action="" method="post">
  
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" id="tmcategory">
  <b>Category:</b> 
 <select id="columns" onchange="document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML=this.value">
   <option value="Result A"> Category 1 </option>
  <option value="Result B"> Category 2 </option>
  <option value="Result C"> Category 3 </option>
 </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td> 
  <table class="left">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="tmtitle">Row 1 Title</span><br><span class="tmsubtitle">Row 1 Subtitle</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="tmtitle">Row 2 Title</span><br><span class="tmsubtitle">Row 2 Subtitle</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="tmtitle">Row 3 Title</span><br><span class="tmsubtitle">Row 3 Subtitle</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    </td>
    
    <td>  
  <table class="right">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="row1">Result A</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="row2">Result D</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span id="row3">Result G</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I have only been able to accomplish this change for the first row because I'm not sure how to add multiple onChange elements or whatever it is that I need to do here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: take a look at [this pen](https://codepen.io/esraglia/pen/XWrKjjN). Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, except in the right column when rows 2 & 3 update, they should actually be different values from row 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your html code, before closing the `<\body>` tag, insert this

```
<script>
document.getElementById('columns').addEventListener("change", function(){
  switch(this.value){
    case 'Result A':
      document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML='A';
      document.getElementById('row2').innerHTML='B';
      document.getElementById('row3').innerHTML='C';
      break;
    case 'Result B':
      document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML='D';
      document.getElementById('row2').innerHTML='E';
      document.getElementById('row3').innerHTML='F';
      break;
    case 'Result C':
      document.getElementById('row1').innerHTML='G';
      document.getElementById('row2').innerHTML='H';
      document.getElementById('row3').innerHTML='I';
      break;
  }
})
</script>
```

This is fine in your case, but if your script is longer, it is recommended to include it in a separate javascript file. For example, create a file like `scrpt.js` with the code inside, and in the html insert the file like this (in case it is saved in the same directory as the html file.

`<script src="./scrpt.js"><\script>`

Comment: Thanks! I added this before the '</body>' tag, changed "stuff" to a few different things, and left everything else the same and nothing changed. Should I be removing another piece of code somewhere?

Comment: you should remove the `onchange=...` in your select tag.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to implement your code, but it's only changing each row to a static value. For each drop-down category selected, I need to change each cell to something different. Does that make sense? For example, for Category 1, row 1 = A, row 2 = B, row 3 = C. Selecting Category 2 would result in row 1 = D, row 2 = E, row 3 = F. Selecting Category 3 would result in row 1 = G, row 2 = H, row 3 = I. Not necessarily in that order, but just exemplifying a different value for each row, for each selected category.

Comment: refresh the page and take a look at the edited answer